# What's the difference between `os.O_APPEND` and `os.ModeAppend`?

Tags: go

We can specify both of `flag` and `perm` at [`os.OpenFile`](https://godoc.org/os#OpenFile).

They have really similar options, [`O_APPEND`](https://godoc.org/os#O_APPEND) and [`ModeAppend`](https://godoc.org/os#ModeAppend). What's the difference between them?

```
f, _ := os.OpenFile("access.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, os.ModeAppend|0644)
```

Comment: documentation for reference : https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-constants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `flag` specify the flags used on the system call to open the file while `perm` sets the File mode on the file. The file mode includes the permissions and type of file eg. symlink, directory, etc...

`os.O_APPEND` tells the underlying OS that all the write calls you do on that file handler should always append to the file so you don't need to set the offset to write on the correct part of the file.

`ModeAppend` sets the file mode to be append. This means that the this file can only be modified by appending to it, not by rewriting the file contents. The specifics of this depends on the OS and file system you are using. I believe Plan 9, implements it by ignoring the offset on any write call to the file and always appending to it, while in linux it means that the file can only be open for writing in append mode. I think that on most linux distros you need to be root to set the file mode to append.

In 99.99% of cases you just want to use `perm` to set the file permissions `rwx`. In your case if you want to open a file and append to it you should use:

```
// os.O_WRONLY tells the computer you are only going to writo to the file, not read
// os.O_CREATE tells the computer to create the file if it doesn't exist
// os.O_APPEND tells the computer to append to the end of the file instead of overwritting or truncating it
f, err := os.OpenFile("access.log", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0644)
```

You might have only ignore the return error on `os.OpenFile` to put the example online, but you should get used to always checking for errors. You have no idea how many users ran into trouble when starting with go because they ignore the errors. Sometimes is something stupid and easy to fix like a typo, but if you ignore the error you don't know what the issue is.

You can read more about the append file mode [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3634/what-does-the-a-in-chattr-ia-do).